# margin right doesn't apply on container

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a container with width 200vw and I want add margin on left and right but for some reasons margin right doesn't apply

```css
.container {
  width: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 15%;
}

.container>div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 700px;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  /* margin-right: 50rem; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give **padding** instead of a margin if you want space between two sides.

```
.container {
  width: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 15%;
}
```